# SQL yes or no to repeat function

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, repeat

```
goto1:

           --- update tabellen
    update dgdtw_lockedinfo set ciuserid = couserid where locknr = &lock;
    update dgdtw_topografie set locknr = '' where locknr = &lock;
    update dgdtw_topografie set verval=sysdate where id= &lock;
    commit;

    accept var prompt ' yes or no '

    if (var = yes) then 
    goto1

    and if (var = no)
       exit
    end if
```

need to repeat a function if user inputs yes

is there a way to repeat command by input?

Comment: sql is a query language, not a programming language. If you want functionality you should use a programming language to make the queries

Comment: should be something like    if (&var = 'yes') ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must do this, use recursion via the start command to loop.

Create a 'end of recursion' file `stop.sql` with content:

```
prompt OK, end of repeat
exit
```

Create a file `repeat.sql` with the following content:

```
set echo off verify off

select 'Your SQL statements go here' from dual;

accept var prompt 'Repeat the SQL statement [yes or no] ? '

define doit = 'stop.sql'
column doit new_value doit noprint
set termout off
select 'repeat.sql' doit from dual where upper('&var') like 'Y%';
set termout on
start &doit.
```

This is an example run:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Jan 11 23:30:24 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options


'YOURSQLSTATEMENTSGOHERE'
---------------------------
Your SQL statements go here

Repeat the SQL statement [yes or no] ? yes

'YOURSQLSTATEMENTSGOHERE'
---------------------------
Your SQL statements go here

Repeat the SQL statement [yes or no] ? y

'YOURSQLSTATEMENTSGOHERE'
---------------------------
Your SQL statements go here

Repeat the SQL statement [yes or no] ? n
OK, no further repetitions.
```

Comment: can you help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926569/oracle-plsql-if-not-found-repeat?noredirect=1#comment57587868_34926569)?